# How should I integrate a form wizard into django-cms?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-cms, django-formwizard

I am creating a custom django-cms plugin, but would like to use a multi-step form. This is because many of the plugin options that should be rendered should be dependent on a a choice made in step 1 of the form.

The CMSPluginBase model extends admin.ModelAdmin, which usually is coupled to only one form. This blog post suggests that I could allow a ModelAdmin class to render multiple forms by mapping CRUD urls to a custom wizard view: http://blog.stanisla.us/2009/10/28/using-a-formwizard-in-the-django-admin/.

Could we do a similar thing in the django-cms? I think it would be hard to not damage the rest of the django-cms functionality.

I have also considered overwriting the get_form function on the CMSPluginBase, but this gives you nowhere to store form data from previous steps.

Comment: You would most likely have to serialize your previous form(s) data and hold it in session until you reach the final form, or ajax your form such that all of the steps are there, but shown/hidden/populated all in one view.